# Special properties of connected hypergraphs with fewer edges than vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a connected graph *G* which has *n* vertices and *m* edges. If *m* = *n* − 1, then we know immediately that *G* is a tree; which is notable because it has no cycles — between any two vertices, there is exactly one path. If *m* = *n*, we know that *G* contains exactly one cycle. And if *m* > *n*, we know that *G* has multiple cycles. (Note that *m* < *n* − 1 is impossible for connected graphs.)

Now consider a connected hypergraph *H*, where each edge contains exactly *k* vertices (it is *k-uniform*), where *k* ≥ 2. Is there any similar sort of structural property of *H*, or graph class to which *H* belongs, if it has exactly *n* edges? At most *n* − 1 edges?

**More precisely:** suppose that there is a mapping from the edges to the vertices, such that each edge is mapped to a distinct vertex to which it is incident. (If you look at the factor graph *F* of the hypergraph — a bipartite graph between a collection of "hyperedge-nodes" and "vertex nodes", where a hyperedge-node *e* is adjacent to a vertex-node *v* in *F*, if and only if *e* is an edge in *H* incident to *v* — then this is equivalent to there being a matching which covers the hyperedge-nodes.) Given that *H* which has such a mapping, suppose that the mapping is in fact bijective. Does this entail any important properties of *H*? What if this function is injective, but not surjective?

Comment: Note: there is at least one analogous property of hypergraphs to trees: if there are precisely $(n-1)/(k-1)$ edges, then there are still unique "paths" in the hypergraph between any pair of nodes; and again, fewer edges are impossible whilst remaining connected. However, I am hoping to find out properties which hold or which fail to hold with very close to *n* edges, if any are known.

Comment: A _clutter_ is a pair (V,E) where E is a collection of subsets of V each containing two or more vertices and harboring no containments. The _density_ of a connected clutter C=(V,E) is $\kappa(C)=\sum_{e\in E}(|e|-1)-|V|$.
A clutter C with two or more edges is a _tree_ if $\kappa(C)=-1$.

Comment: @GusWiseman: interesting! In the $k$-regular case, clutters are quite a natural subclass to consider. And it would seem that the pertinent property of clutter which is a *tree* is again acyclicity, that there are unique paths between any pair of vertices. However, this criterion does not compare number of edges, but their collective size; and indeed, in the $k$-regular case, the condition $\kappa(C) = -1$ is equivalent to $m = (n-1)/(k-1)$ for $n = |V|$ and $m = |E|$, which I describe in my preceding comment.

Comment: For (V,E) a clutter consider the set of set partitions p of E whose set of unions Union^*(p) is a clutter that is tree. This poset has a unique maximum set partition s (but I haven't found an easy proof of this fact). The blocks of s are clutters that I call _blobs_. In other words, every clutter is a tree of blobs. Blobs are not characterized by density value or 2-connectedness, and I haven't found a way to enumerate them directly. But they can be defined as clutters with no contraction that is a tree.